# How to syncup MongoDB failed over with working replica machine?

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

MongoDB replication, it has 3 servers(Server1, Server2, Server3). Due to any reason, **Server1** goes down and **Server2** acts as Primary and **Server3** as Secondary mode.

**Query**: As **Server1** is down and after 2-3 hours we made it up(running). The 3 hrs gap between **Server1** data and **Server2** data, how it will be sync up?

Answer (score 2):

The primary maintains an [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/#replica-set-oplog) detailing all of the writes that have been done to the data.  The oplog is capped by size, the oldest entries are automatically removed to keep it below the configured size.

When a secondary node replicates from the primary, it reads the oplog and creates a local copy.  If a secondary is offline for a period of time, when it comes back online, it will ask the primary for all oplog entries since the last one that it successfully copied.

If the primary still has the entry that the secondary most recently saw, the secondary will begin applying the events it missed.

If the primary no longer has that entry, the secondary will log a message that it is too stale to catch up, and manual intervention will be required.  This would usually require a manual [resync](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/index.html#resync-a-member-of-a-replica-set)